Finding a common ancestor using QGIS
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsSpatialIndex, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsRenderContext
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QColor
from collections import Counter

trafolar_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('transformator_dagitim')[0]  # Trafolar katmanı
kesiciler_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('kesici')[0]  # Kesiciler katmanı
ayirici_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ayirici')[0]  # Ayırıcılar katmanı

kesici_index = QgsSpatialIndex(kesiciler_layer.getFeatures())
ayirici_index = QgsSpatialIndex(ayirici_layer.getFeatures())

target_center_codes = [38737, 38621, 38622, 38620, 38619, 38618, 38615, 38616, 38617, 38736, 38748, 46534]

kesici_candidates = []
ayirici_candidates = []

for trafo_feat in trafolar_layer.getFeatures():
    trafo_center_code = trafo_feat['merkez_kodu']
    
    if trafo_center_code in target_center_codes:
        trafo_geom = trafo_feat.geometry()
        
        nearest_kesici_ids = kesici_index.nearestNeighbor(trafo_geom.asPoint(), 1)
        nearest_ayirici_ids = ayirici_index.nearestNeighbor(trafo_geom.asPoint(), 1)

        if nearest_kesici_ids:
            kesici_candidates.append(nearest_kesici_ids[0])

        if nearest_ayirici_ids:
            ayirici_candidates.append(nearest_ayirici_ids[0])

selected_kesici_id = None
selected_ayirici_id = None

if kesici_candidates:
    kesici_counts = Counter(kesici_candidates)
    most_common_kesici = kesici_counts.most_common(1)
    if most_common_kesici and most_common_kesici[0][1] > 1:
        selected_kesici_id = most_common_kesici[0][0]

if not selected_kesici_id and ayirici_candidates:
    ayirici_counts = Counter(ayirici_candidates)
    most_common_ayirici = ayirici_counts.most_common(1)
    if most_common_ayirici and most_common_ayirici[0][1] > 1:
        selected_ayirici_id = most_common_ayirici[0][0]

render_context = QgsRenderContext()  # Render context oluşturulması

if selected_kesici_id:
    kesiciler_layer.selectByIds([selected_kesici_id])
    kesici_request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(selected_kesici_id)
    kesici_feat = next(kesiciler_layer.getFeatures(kesici_request))
    kesici_symbol = kesiciler_layer.renderer().symbolForFeature(kesici_feat, render_context)
    kesici_symbol.setColor(QColor('red'))
    kesiciler_layer.triggerRepaint()
    print("The common cutter is marked in red.")

elif selected_ayirici_id:
    ayirici_layer.selectByIds([selected_ayirici_id])
    ayirici_request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(selected_ayirici_id)
    ayirici_feat = next(ayirici_layer.getFeatures(ayirici_request))
    ayirici_symbol = ayirici_layer.renderer().symbolForFeature(ayirici_feat, render_context)
    ayirici_symbol.setColor(QColor('blue'))
    ayirici_layer.triggerRepaint()
    print("The common separator is marked in blue.")


I have transformer_distribution elements that I have circled in red, there are breakers and disconnectors to which they are connected, and the breaker elements I show in yellow color show which transformers they feed. If the center_code data comes from the transformers in the place I marked with number 1, I want to find the breaker number 1, if the data comes from the number 2, I want to find the number 2, if the data comes from the number 2, I want to find the number 2, if it comes from the number 3, it only finds the number 3, but in some cases, the center_code can come from both number 1 and number 2, in this case I want it to find the number 4, that is, I am trying to find the common ancestor, in fact, I am trying to find the center where they receive common energy according to the center code. I am trying to process with the code below, but I cannot get the result I want.
In addition, I want to see how many percent of the upward transport operation according to the operation it performs, for example, data came from 10 transformers at number 1, information came from 5 transformers from number 2, and this was the common ancestor.


I did not know what to share as data, after researching on the internet, I tried to find other breakers, disconnectors or transformers affected by the dirt breaker using the following queries, but I did not get any results
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
--------------------------
CREATE SEQUENCE nodes_seq;
--------------------------
CREATE TABLE nodes AS
  SELECT 
    nextval('nodes_seq') AS id,
    (ST_DumpPoints(shape)).geom AS geometry
  FROM public.og_hat;
 --------------------------
 CREATE INDEX idx_nodes_geom ON nodes USING GIST (geometry);
  --------------------------
 CREATE TABLE edges AS
  SELECT 
    og.objectid AS id, 
    og.shape AS geometry,
    n1.id AS source, 
    n2.id AS target, 
    ST_Length(og.shape) AS length
  FROM public.og_hat og
  JOIN nodes n1 ON ST_DWithin(og.shape, n1.geometry, 0.01)
  JOIN nodes n2 ON ST_DWithin(ST_EndPoint(og.shape), n2.geometry, 0.01);
 --------------------------
  
CREATE INDEX idx_source ON edges(source);
CREATE INDEX idx_target ON edges(target);
--------------------------

CREATE INDEX idx_transformator_geom ON transformator USING GIST (shape);
CREATE INDEX idx_ayirici_geom ON ayirici USING GIST (shape);
CREATE INDEX idx_kesici_geom ON kesici USING GIST (shape);

--------------------------
WITH source_node AS (
  SELECT n.id AS node_id
  FROM nodes n
  JOIN kesici k ON ST_DWithin(n.geometry, k.shape, 0.01)
  WHERE k.objectid = 20809
  LIMIT 1
),
driving_distance AS (
  SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
    'SELECT id, source, target, length AS cost FROM edges', 
    (SELECT node_id FROM source_node),
    10000
  )
)

SELECT 
  dd.node, dd.cost,
  t.objectid AS trafo_id, t.merkez_adi,
  a.objectid AS ayirici_id, a.aciklama,
  k2.objectid AS kesici_id, k2.aciklama
FROM driving_distance dd
LEFT JOIN nodes n ON dd.node = n.id
LEFT JOIN transformator t ON ST_DWithin(n.geometry, t.shape, 0.01)
LEFT JOIN ayirici a ON ST_DWithin(n.geometry, a.shape, 0.01)
LEFT JOIN kesici k2 ON ST_DWithin(n.geometry, k2.shape, 0.01)
WHERE dd.node != (SELECT node_id FROM source_node);


Can you please share some data with us?
